# Ansible failing to execute the command by becoming super user?

Tags: linux, shell, ansible, ansible-2.x, sudoers

I want to execute the shell command, by becoming superuser, going to user directory and executing command, but I am failing in my attempt to do so, Everytime I get stuck with error.

**playbook**: *sudo.yml*

```
---
- name: Test playbook
  hosts: targets
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
  - name: install kubernetes
    shell: |
            export https_proxy=proxy
            yum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes
            systemctl enable --now kubelet
    become: true
    become_user: tania
    become_method: su
```

**Command**: *$ ansible-playbook playbooks/sudo.yml -i hosts --ask-become-pass*

**Error:**

```
TASK [install kubernetes] ****************************************************************************************************
fatal: [machine1]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "export https_proxy=proxy\nyum install -y kubelet kubeadm kubectl --disableexcludes=kubernetes\nsystemctl enable --now kubelet\n", "delta": "0:10:04.325228", "end": "2023-06-16 10:45:53.301934", "msg": "non-zero return code", "rc": 1, "start": "2023-06-16 10:35:48.976706", "stderr": "sudo: timed out reading password\nsudo: timed out reading password", "stderr_lines": ["sudo: timed out reading password", "sudo: timed out reading password"], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}
```

I do not want to execute command as: *sudo < command >* but as *sudo -i* then *command*

**Ansible.cfg**

```
[defaults]
interpreter_python = /usr/bin/python2
inventory = $HOME/obsw_ansible/hosts
playbook_dir = $HOME/obsw_ansible/playbooks/
remote_user = $USER
log_path = /var/log/ansible.logs
display_skipped_hosts = True
system_warnings = True
show_custom_stats = True
sudo_user      = $USER
host_key_checking = False
ask_sudo_pass  = False
remote_port    = 22
deprecation_warnings = False

[inventory]
enable_plugins = ini, yaml

[privilege_escalation]
become_method = sudo
become_user = $USER
become_ask_pass = True

[paramiko_connection]
host_key_auto_add = True

[connection]
ssh_args = -C -o ControlMaster=auto -o ControlPersist=60s
```

*$ ansible --version*

```
ansible [core 2.11.12]
  config file = /home/tania/obsw_ansible/ansible.cfg
  configured module search path = ['/home/tania/.ansible/plugins/modules', '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules']
  ansible python module location = /usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ansible
  ansible collection location = /home/tania/.ansible/collections:/usr/share/ansible/collections
  executable location = /usr/local/bin/ansible
  python version = 3.6.8 (default, Jan 11 2023, 08:43:50) [GCC 8.5.0 20210514 (Red Hat 8.5.0-16)]
  jinja version = 2.10.1
  libyaml = True
```

I am providing password still getting error. please help

Suggested changes to playbook or workaround approach. Inspite of providing the password I am still getting same error. Please suggest what am I missing.